# GoogleCharts with KnockoutJS custom binding only draws first chart but not the rest

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, google-visualization, custom-binding

I have been looking for a solution to this problem but could not find anywhere. Therefore I am requesting you guys here.

I am trying to bind GoogleBarChart with KnockoutJS model view. All Binding events get called perfectly fine, but somehow it only draws the first chart.

Binding is as follow:

```js
// View Model 1
function ViewModel1() {    
    var self = this;
    self.ViewModel1_BarData =  ko.computed(function () {
         
        return new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['EmailAddress', 'Received'],
          ['email1@mail.com', 12],
          ['email2@mail.com', 20],
          ['email3@mail.com', 15]
    ]);
    });
  
  
  // View Model 2
function ViewModel2() {    
    var self = this;
    self.ViewModel2_BarData =  ko.computed(function () {
         
        return new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Server', 'Occupied Space'],
          ['server1', 10],
          ['server2', 20],
          ['server3', 40]
    ]);
    });
  
  
  
// Knockout Custom Binding for googleBarChart
  
ko.bindingHandlers.googleBarChart = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(element);
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, 'googleBarChart', chart);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var options = allBindings.get('chartOptions') || {};        
        options = ko.unwrap(options);
      
        var chart = ko.utils.domData.get(element,'googleBarChart');
        chart.draw(value, options);
    }
};
```

```html
<!-- First Chart -->
<div id="ViewModel1Bindng_div">
  
  <div id="ViewModel1_bar_div" data-bind="googleBarChart: ViewModel1_BarData, chartOptions: {
    width: 400, legend: { position: 'none' }, chart: { title: 'title-text', subtitle: 'subtitle-text' }}"></div>
  
</div>

<!-- Second Chart -->

<div id="ViewModel2Binding_div">
 
  <div id="ViewModel2_bar_div" data-bind="googleBarChart: ViewModel2_BarData, chartOptions: {
    width: 400,legend: { position: 'none' }, chart: { title: 'title-text', subtitle: 'subtitle-text' }}">
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Rohail

Comment: can you show us  `applyBindings` part in your code . cheers

Comment: applyBindings information has been added in <script></script> tag. @supercool

Comment: By the look its neat it should work can you give a try keeping in document.ready inside script tag .

Comment: Nope, just tried, did'nt work either. @supercool

Comment: There's a spelling difference between your 2nd div name and what you bind your 2nd model to, Binding vs Bindng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled the element id here:

```
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel2_model , document.getElementById("ViewModel2Bindng_div"))
```

It should be:

```
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel2_model , document.getElementById("ViewModel2Binding_div"))
```

I have updated your snippet to work.

```js
// View Model 1
function ViewModel1() {
  var self = this;
  self.ViewModel1_BarData = ko.computed(function() {

    return new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['EmailAddress', 'Received'],
      ['email1@mail.com', 12],
      ['email2@mail.com', 20],
      ['email3@mail.com', 15]
    ]);
  });
}

// View Model 2
function ViewModel2() {
  var self = this;
  self.ViewModel2_BarData = ko.computed(function() {

    return new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Server', 'Occupied Space'],
      ['server1', 10],
      ['server2', 20],
      ['server3', 40]
    ]);
  });
}


// Knockout Custom Binding for googleBarChart

ko.bindingHandlers.googleBarChart = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(element);
    ko.utils.domData.set(element, 'googleBarChart', chart);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var options = allBindings.get('chartOptions') || {};
    options = ko.unwrap(options);

    var chart = ko.utils.domData.get(element, 'googleBarChart');
    chart.draw(value, options);
  }
};


var ViewModel1_model = new ViewModel1();
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel1_model, document.getElementById("ViewModel1Bindng_div"));


var ViewModel2_model = new ViewModel2();
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel2_model, document.getElementById("ViewModel2Binding_div"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart'],'language':'en'}]}">
</script>

<!-- First Chart -->
<div id="ViewModel1Bindng_div">

  <div id="ViewModel1_bar_div" data-bind="googleBarChart: ViewModel1_BarData, chartOptions: {
    width: 400, legend: { position: 'none' }, chart: { title: 'title-text', subtitle: 'subtitle-text' }}"></div>

</div>

<!-- Second Chart -->

<div id="ViewModel2Binding_div">

  <div id="ViewModel2_bar_div" data-bind="googleBarChart: ViewModel2_BarData, chartOptions: {
    width: 400,legend: { position: 'none' }, chart: { title: 'title-text', subtitle: 'subtitle-text' }}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Anish for your help. I was able to resolve the issue by comparing it with your code. However the problem i found was with the google chart class i was using to create a chart object. It was  "var chart = new google.charts.Bar(element);"  earlier whereas it should be "var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(element);"